# NSBundle pathForResource not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsbundle

On iOS 6 this block of code works fine:

```
- (NSString*)cLocalImageName
{
     [self willAccessValueForKey:@"cLocalImageName"];
     NSString*pathToImage;
     if ([self.cIsUserCreated boolValue]) {
         pathToImage =  [self primitiveValueForKey:@"cLocalImageName"];
     }else{
         pathToImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[self primitiveValueForKey:@"cLocalImageName"] ofType:@".png"];
     }
     [self didAccessValueForKey:@"cLocalImageName"];
     return pathToImage;
}
```

Namely this line always returns the correct file path:

```
 pathToImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[self primitiveValueForKey:@"cLocalImageName"] ofType:@".png"];
```

However, on iOS 5 that line always returns nil, and I instead have to call:

```
 pathToImage = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[self primitiveValueForKey:@"cLocalImageName"]]];
```

Can anyone give me any insight into why this is an issue on iOS 5?

Things I've ruled out:

• [self primitiveValueForKey:@"cLocalImageName"] is not returning nil.

• The .png objects are in fact present in the compiled .app package once the app is built.

Comment: I wont even bother to ask why primitiveValueForKey would return an NSString which is not a primitive value.

Comment: It's a Core Data thing, I think they are using primitive in a different sense than the norm.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Shouldn't this line:

```
pathToImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[self primitiveValueForKey:@"cLocalImageName"] ofType:@".png"];
```

be this:

```
pathToImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[self primitiveValueForKey:@"cLocalImageName"] ofType:@"png"];
```

?

Comment: Oh wild, I didn't realize I had included the '.', but now that you mention it I realize I usually don't do that. Any idea why ".png" works on iOS 6? They must have changed how the method checks extensions?

Comment: Perhaps they realised it was a common typo, and one they could easily handle, or maybe just a side-effect of a change to the implementation? Slightly annoying it works on one and not the other though!

Comment: Ha. Thanks paulbailey.  Yes iOS5 doesn't like the '.' symbol but iOS6 handles it fine.  Painful figuring that one out!!

Comment: Yep, I moved to iOS 7 recently and today I have to fix this bug on iOS 5. It's clear that iOS 7 & iOS 6 are more intelligent than iOS5 because they can adapt better.

Comment: Yea !! It helps a lot ... Great Work .